# /usr/bin/find slow with some options

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Today I tried to run a simple `find` command in Iterm, and found it to be unusably slow even for simple queries.  Here's the simplest example:

```
time find . -depth 0
.

real    0m11.056s
user    0m0.571s
sys 0m5.186s
```

I get similar results from any directory, and whether using ITerm, Terminal, or VS Code's integrated terminal.  I'm not setting any find or file system options in my .bash_profile or other startup scripts.

What could be slowing it down?

- Big Sur: 11.2.3
- Iterm: 3.4.8
- Terminal: 2.11
- shell: bash 5.1.4(1)-release via homebrew
- VS Code: 1.57.1

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this was simple user error. The option I should have been using was `-maxdepth n`, not `-depth n`.  Instead of only searching the directories of interest, `-depth n` recursively searches the entire tree starting from the specified directory, and only matches those at that are `n` directories deep. And the issue was not from any directory, all the directories I tried before asking the question contained a lot of child directories and files.